# Converting .jks file to .p12

Tags: java

I have an issue while **converting** `.jks` to `.p12`

```
bash-4.1$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore adorbcert.jks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore adorbcert.p12
Enter destination keystore password:
Enter source keystore password:
Problem importing entry for alias adorbcerts: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported.
```

and I am **using java**

```
java version "1.7.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You may need `-trustcacerts`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting .jks to p12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846828/converting-jks-to-p12)

Comment: It is not really a duplicate because he already knows the syntax of how to convert a JKS keystore to PKCS12. The problem here is that until Java 8 this only worked with keyEntry and privateKeyEntry.

Comment: OK, a better duplicate would be [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160189/creating-pkcs12-using-java-api-failes-due-to-error-java-security-keystoreexcept). Why are you creating a .p12 file without a private key? If it's just the certificate you're converting, a .cer file is the normal format to use.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with keytool from Java 7 or earlier, but it is with Java 8.

Also the keystore type only needs to be specified if it is not JKS.